# Suggestions for DC/DC converters with digital control

Tags: digital-logic, dc-dc-converter, specifications

I am under quite some time pressure and I need to put together a document about how several DC/DC converters (preferably buck) with digital control compare to each other. I am pretty clueless, I have already pored over tons of datasheets, but I got little useful data, most of the converters out there have analog control. (Maybe I'm just so bad at finding anything on the web...)
What I need is something like the [UCD74106](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucd74106.pdf) from TI. It should have an external PWM input which can come from e.g. a microcontroller.
The specs I am looking for are:

- V_in = 48 V
- V_out = 1.3 V to 24 V (programmable)
- single input/single output
- *can* be paralleled
- **any** power range

It would be nice to have datasheets with efficiency curves. Something like 'typical efficiency is blah-blah %' is not very helpful...

**EDIT**: Other examples of what I have in mind: [NDM1-12-120](http://products.cui.com/CUI_NDM1-12-120_Datasheet.pdf?fileID=4399) and [NDM1-25-120](http://products.cui.com/CUI_NDM1-25-120_Datasheet.pdf?fileID=4399), both from CUI

**EDIT 2**: I need the efficiency curves to see how the converter behaves at partial load. Also I am interested in finding the (approximative) load current at which the maximum efficiency is achieved (usually below rated current).

And yes, I need *digital* control! This has been explicitly stated in my assignment... The idea is to be able to reprogram the converters whenever necessary and to make them SMB/PMB capable.

I listed the datasheets to show, what I have found so far and to give an example of what I would like to have. Unfortunately 3 are not enough... I'd need a dozen or so.

Comment: I think this is an unsuitable question. It should be closed as it stands.

Comment: @LeonHeller: What exactly would make it suitable?

Comment: The Faq explains why it is unsuitable. It's nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: @LeonHeller: I would classify it under design choice problem and IMHO that qualifies it for a valid question.

Comment: You are asking us to do your shopping for (vaguely specified) suitable items for you. Are we expected to find a dozen examples for you?

Comment: Nope, I'm not shopping. I am trying to make a comparison of digital DC/DC converters for the given voltage ranges! I need to justify why they might be better than analog ones in a particular setting. My problem is that I _can't find_ more digitally controlled DC/DC converters. I tried TI, CUI, Linear, Vicor, etc... I thought some of you might have used digitally controlled DC/DC converters and might give examples.

Comment: Re "And yes, I need digital control!"  Yes, BUT is this at the IC level or at the solution module level? As Olin says, in the real world you but a converter that does th ejob best when matched with a microcontroller of choice. If best = "does job xxx cheapest" then a microcontroller solution is still liable to feature. | If the spec is "IC **MUST** be digitally controlled, we know it's stupid, don't ask questions" then do it at the IC level. Otherwise be SURE that it's the **IC** that must be digitally capable and not just the overall module.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: I'll stick with the microcontroller. `:)` The truth is that I have little practical experience with digitally controlled DC/DC converters, but I think that only digital control has the required flexibility (see voltage range!). I'm afraid with purely analog solutions I cannot get a stable system with a reasonable effort. Plus it needs some extra communication and remote control features... So I think the uController solution is just fine.

Comment: @LeonHeller, can you attempt to be a bit more welcoming when someone seems to stray. Although this question really seems off topic from the post and shopping, the selected answer seems to show the question was really just looking for help.

Comment: @Kortuk - I suspect you misconstrued my comment". The "we know it's stupid" is an example wording of a spec from someone nknown - such things happen. People say 'we KNOW this doesn't make sense in a sensible world BUT head office says we must XXX because YYY - We KNOW it's stupid but that's the spec". ie NO references to anyone here at all. OR if that is not what you meant please elucidate. [[When I get uncivil it's usually clearer than that - if no women, children small animals or beginning questioners are being hurt then I'm probably being covil. Mostly anyway.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, okay then. No worries, your comment came off as an attack when I read it, so I assumed others could read it that way also. I could also see ways were it was more joking around, but I just edited the original comment, removed yours and left notes. No worries, mine for that is now disappearing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to think about.

First, even "analog" power supply control chips can be "digitally controlled", whatever that really means.  A little external tweaking of the feedback and the output voltage can be varied.  Many have shutdown inputs, but of course that can be accomplished other ways too.

Second, for fancy switching power supply control you can use a microcontroller directly, and obviously have all the digital control you care to program in.  There are whole families of microcontrollers specifically intended for this sort of application.  They have fast A/Ds, decent computer power, and fancy PWM modules that not only have high resolution but additional features like external shutdown modes, complementary outputs, etc.  Check out the dsPIC 33F line from Microchip.  All the high end switching power supply applications we've dealt with in recent years have had a microcontroller doing the closed loop control.  Dedicated chips are more for simple power supplies, like running the microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks! That's really a step forwards! `:)` I considered the Microchip dsPIC24F family with similar capabilities, but (usually) at lower cost.

Comment: The question really is whether there is any such integrated solution? Or I should rather look for the parts separately (e.g. uController, MOSFETs, caps, inductors, resistances, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Few SMPS (Switched Mode Power Supply) IC's have direct PWM control capabilty essentially  anything that can be controlled by an analog signal can be controlled by a digital (eg PWM) signal and a basic duty cycle to %-level converter - essentially an RC or other filter to "restore" the mean DC level.

I do not know why your assignment requires explicit digital control but unless it was very very very very clearly necessarily an internal function of the IC  I would assume that DC controlling signal would suffice. (An explanation of why or IF specific digital control at the IC level is needed would be useful.)

You quite possibly do not understand the use of "typical" in the context mentioned. Achievable efficiency in a given circuit will necessarily vary somewhat between members of a large quantity of IC's of a given type, due to production spread of IC parameters, & component tolerances. Overall real world efficiencies will be affected by inductor quality, variations in Vf of rectifier diode. (or sysnchronous rectifiers), capacitor value variation and quality, PCB layout, phase of the moon, proximity to a bank holiday and more.

Most SMPS data sheets have efficiency curves included which give a ~ midpoint value for assumed variatins i all the applicable parameters. They tend NOT to give expecte spread in efficincy for a given parameterset but you can get a feel for it yourself either by common sense reasoning or by calculation.

Data sheet graphs  usually provide efficincies for mixes of 3 or more variables. For example in the [UCD74106 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucd74106.pdf) that you cite, provides effiency against load current fo w values of Vin. Some data sheets will provide a family of graphs with one variable being varies per graph.

Even with the limited data in Fig2 (below) versus Vout you can deduce that efficiency is relatively sensitive to Vout as for Vout = 2.5V and 3.3V the two curves are almost coincident. Maybe 2% variation in efficiency as Vout
varies by ~ +- 15% and Iout varying from 0.5A to <= 6A.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Maybe my wording of the question is not very clear, because I'm a bit stressed out... `:(` I edited my question again. Maybe this time I can make clear what I need.